# GCM notification received but not displaying

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My android App and server have been configured to receive and send push notifications. My app receives the notification perfectly and it shows up in LogCat whether my app is open, in the background or not running just as it should. However, I'm having a problem getting it to display. No matter what I do, I can't get it to show up in the notification center or come in as an alert that vibrates the phone or makes a sound.

What am I missing? I'm using the GCM Plugin from here: https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova

I've tried getting it to send a notification using NotificationCompat, but I've been unsuccessful.

-->json from GCM passed to this function...

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onMessage - context: " + context);

    // Extract the payload from the message
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        try
        {
            Log.v(ME + ":onMessage extras ", extras.getString("message"));

            JSONObject json;
            json = new JSONObject().put("event", "message");

            // My application on my host server sends back to "EXTRAS" variables message and msgcnt
            // Depending on how you build your server app you can specify what variables you want to send

            json.put("message", extras.getString("message"));
            json.put("msgcnt", extras.getString("msgcnt"));

            Log.v(ME + ":onMessage ", json.toString());

            GCMPlugin.sendJavascript( json );
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle("TEST")
                .setContentText("TEST");
            // Send the MESSAGE to the Javascript application
        }
        catch( JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e(ME + ":onMessage", "JSON exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The goal obviously is to get the test notification to display and then strip the message out of the json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're pretty close, but you're missing a single step. Your code prepares a Notification but doesn't actually show it. Put these lines after your `NotificationCompat.Builder` code:

```java
final int notificationId = 1;
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext()
      .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

The notification id is an arbitrary number that you can use to retrieve the notification if you need to update or remove it later.

Comment: It just appears now, no Noise or anything. And when I click it nothing happens

Comment: Those are all controllable through the notification builder. Check out [the full api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) to get a sense of what's supported. To get click handling, you need to use `setContentIntent()` (which may require you to dig a bit deeper into the Android specifics than Cordova would have had you think). To get sound, you need to call `setSound()` and give it an Uri to a sound file in the `res/raw` directory (don't include the file extension in the Uri).

Comment: I see you noticed npocmaka's plagiarism in tag wikis while reviewing suggested edits too, unfortunately lots of people do not notice :( What do you think we should do? I sent a moderator flag of "other"

Comment: @Doorknob I share your frustration. Setting "other" might help, but the Wikipedia thing is so prevalent I think the site infrastructure should help catch it. We should take this discussion elsewhere: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102314/can-we-do-anything-against-tag-wikis-copy-pasted-from-wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

Use this code! Hope code will help you

`

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

    resultIntent.putExtra("msg", msg);

    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Alert")
            .setContentText("You've received new message.")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    // Set pending intent
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    // Set Vibrate, Sound and Light
    int defaults = 0;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    mNotifyBuilder.setDefaults(defaults);
    // Set the content for Notification
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText("New message from Server");
    // Set autocancel
    mNotifyBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    // Post a notification
    mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
`
```